# Diophantine equations involving the difference between perfect square and perfect cube

Tags: nt.number-theory, diophantine-equations, diophantine-approximation

(a) Do there exist infinitely many triples $(x,y,z)$ of integers with $z\neq 0$ such that
$$
z(x^3-y^2) = x+1.
$$
(b) The same question for
$$
z(x^3-y^2) = y+1.
$$

In other words, are there infinitely many pairs of integers $(x,y)$ not equal to $-1$ such that $x^3-y^2$ is a divisor of (a) $x+1$ and (b) $y+1$.

If not a complete answer, I would be interested in heuristic argument predicting what the answer should be.

If we would have $0<|x^3-y^2|<|x+1|$ only finitely often, this would solve (a), but my computation shows that the difference between perfect square and a cube is sometimes much smaller than $x$.

Comment: Indeed, it is expected by many that for any positive number $c$ there exist infinitely many $x,y \in \mathbb{Z}$ satisfying $|x^3 - y^2| > c|x|^{1/2}$, so purely archimedean arguments will not likely resolve your problem.

Comment: Conjecturally we have (if $x^3\ne y^2$)
$$ |x^3-y^2| \gg |x|^{1/2-\epsilon}, $$
so
$$ |z| = \frac{|x+1|}{|x^3-y^2|}  \ll |x|^{1/2+\epsilon}. $$
It's now tempting to apply the "$abcd$ conjecture" (which is a special case of Vojta's conjecture), but it applies to $a+b+c+d=0$ with $a,b,c,d$ pairwise relatively prime. Your four numbers $zxz^2,zy^2,x,1$ are not pairwise prime, so you'd need to do some work dealing with that.

Comment: Could there even be parametric polynomial solutions?

Comment: This is highly unlikely. The search returns some small solutions, and then no more solutions up to a large margin. If there would be parametric polynomial solutions with not too large degree and coefficients, it would produce some moderately large solutions.

Answer (score 1):

Just to point out that this is related to integral points
on elliptic curves, which is well studied topic.

Treating $z$ as parameter, your equation (a) is equivalent to
integral points on the
elliptic curve
$$E_z : x^3-\frac1z x-\frac1z=y^2 \qquad (1)$$.

sagemath can't compute integral points on non-integral curves,
but we may define

$$E'_z: u^3-z^3 u-z^5=v^2 \qquad (2) $$.

(2) and (1) are birationally equivalent
and (2) has many integral points, but not all of them are integral
on (1).

The map from (2) to (1) is given by $(u,v) \mapsto \frac{u}{z^2},\frac{v}{z^3}$

So the solutions of (1) are integral points on (2) with $z^2 \mid u$.

Using this approach sagemath found two solutions: $(3,5,2)$
and $(1,0,2)$.

The experiments with sage are slow, because it computes
the generators of the elliptic curve.

Comment: $(x,y,z)=(5,11,3)$ is a solution to (b).

Comment: @GerryMyerson I am not treating (b), only (a). Just edited.